# How to remove the cell selection style color when once again showing the table view in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am new to iphone development.I created a table displaying my contents.If i select a row ,it state is highlighted in blue color and navigates to another view and if i click the back button it navigates back to the table showing  the clicked cell in blue color,i want to remove the highlighted color on  table while navigating back to its view.How can i do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally got it by implementing this in my table view class.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated  
{  
    NSIndexPath *tableSelection = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];  
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:tableSelection animated:NO];  
}
```

Answer (score 48):

I think the generally accepted way to do this is to deselect the cell as you're navigating to the new view. Instead of viewWillAppear, use the tableview delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath and the same deselectRowAtIndexPath you were using.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES];
}
```

(and by generally accepted, I mean "stuff I most often see in example code". It depends on what you want it to look like in the end)

Comment: Deselecting the cell this way causes the animation to occur as the new scene loads rather than as the scene reappears, which is what @Warrior's answer does. Depends on what you want, I guess.

Comment: Agree, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 14):

You are doing it wrong, on cellForRowAtIndexPath method. use this

```
 [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

On your UITableViewCells

This would be the correct way if you wanted the cell not to be highlighted nor on selection touch neither on coming back to view. If you only want the cell deselected when coming back to view the other solutions are more suitable.

Comment: For Xamarin: 
cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
Swift 3:
cell.selectionStyle = .none;

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of `viewDidAppear:` should take care of that for you. If you did override that method in your table view controller, don't forget to call `[super viewDidAppear:animated]` in your override method.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            tableview.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }
    }
```